# How to access a GString pointed to by a gpointer from a GHashTable

Tags: c, glib

The C code

```
#include <glib.h>
//...
GHashTable *hash = g_hash_table_new(NULL, NULL);
GString val;

g_hash_table_insert(hash, (int*)5, g_string_new("Bar"));
val = g_hash_table_lookup(hash, (int*)5); // line 10

printf("Foo ~ %s\n", val->str); // line 16

if (NULL == val) // line 18
    printf("Eet ees null!\n");
```

Which produced:

> > ctest.c:10: error: incompatible types in assignment
> >
> > ctest.c:16: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'GString')
> >
> > ctest.c:18: error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'void *' and 'GString')

What am I doing wrong? :(

**EDIT**: Some might be confused and ask ask themselves "Why didn't she use `g_string_printf()`?"

Because I need to access `gchar *str`, printing was just my way of "debugging" it.

**EDIT**: Added line 18, and commented the spazzing lines (yes, lots of whites-paces all over the place. I'm dreadful, I know).

Comment: I don't think you included line 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `g_string_new` returns a `GString *`. So that's what's getting stored in the hash. And the function `g_hash_table_lookup` returns a `void *`. You likely want something like this:

```
GString *val;
val = g_hash_table_lookup(hash, (int*)5);
printf("Foo ~ %s\n", val->str);
```

Comment: You saved me once more! Thank you! ♥

Answer (score 1):

A GString structure is declared as:

```
struct GString {
  gchar  *str;
  gsize len;
  gsize allocated_len;
};
```

so to access the string just use the `.` operator:

```
printf("%s\n", val.str)
```

Also passing `(int*) 5` as an argument to your function is probably wrong. This converts the integer value `5` to a pointer. But what you want is a pointer to an `int` where the `int` value is 5.

To do this you can either use a compound literal:  `&(int) {5}` or use a pointer to an object of type `int`:

```
int bla = 5;  // and you pass &bla as the argument of your function
```

Answer (score 0):

`val->str` should be `val.str` - it's not a pointer. This also means you can't do `if (NULL == val)`.